# How many different values can $XY$ take?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let's suppose that $ABC9$ is a $4$-digit number and $XY$ is a
> $2$-digit number that is the remainder of the division of $ABC9$ by
> $18$. How many different values can $XY$ take?

It seems that we want to count the number of different, possible remainders of $ABC9$ by $18$. Then, since $18 = 9\times 2$

$$ABC9 = 10^3A+10^2B+10C+9\equiv 2\pmod{2}$$

$$ABC9 = 10^3A+10^2B+10C+9\equiv A+B+C\pmod{9}$$

Now, we can evaluate

$$ABC9\pmod{18}$$

But can I hear your feedback as to whether I am on the right track?

**EDIT:** By division algorithm,

$$ABC9 = 18\times D + XY$$

Where $XY<18$ and $ABC9-18$ is an odd number, so $XY\in\{11, 13, 15, 17\}$ are the only possibilities.

Comment: How do you know that they are all actually possibile?  Maybe there is a complicated argument why $15$ isn't possible. If you can't find any such argument, that still doesn't means there isn't any. For example, a cursory reading of the problem might one think to conclude that every integert from $10$ to $17$ are the only possible solutions.

Comment: The numbers $1009,1019,1029,1039,1049,1059,1069,1079,1089$ are enough to get all $9$ ODD $XY$.